# Downscaling a JavaFX Application

Tags: user-interface, javafx, resize, scale

I am trying to find a universal solution to make any fxml document scale by a certain factor and i tried using the "javafx.scene.transform.Scale" to achieve that but it messes up my window,
[The Window when i run the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRBLB.png)

```
public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {
    
    private final double scaleFactor = 0.5; // Scale factor (0.5 for 50% scaling)

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainGUI.fxml"));
    Pane root = loader.load();

    // Scale the root pane
    Scale scale = new Scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor,0,0);
    root.getTransforms().add(scale);
    

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.minWidthProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().multiply(scaleFactor));
    primaryStage.minHeightProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().multiply(scaleFactor));
    primaryStage.show();
    
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

i tried fitting the stage to the scene but i am starting to belief that the scene must be the full sice bc it wont change no matter what i try